# How to use parameter as index in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a recursive template so that I can update a count.  In the template, I want to be able to use the current count to be able to access the node whose index is the current count.

```
<!-- in the template -->

<xsl:param name="i"/>
<xsl:param name="count"/>      

<NewNode>
    <xsl:value-of select="//ACommonElementInTheDocument[$i]/MyElement"/> : <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
</NewNode>
```

I get $i printed out correctly, as expected, but I'm not able to reference the element, although this works perfectly when I use XMLSpy to test the XPath.

Could anyone point out the glaring mistake I'm making please?...

Many thanks

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for the only correct solution at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you have declared the parameter. But my guess is that this is a type casting problem. What happens if you try:

```
//ACommonElementInTheDocument[number($i)]/MyElement
```

Or in XSLT 2.0 you could also use one of the XML Schema types:

```
//ACommonElementInTheDocument[xs:integer($i)]/MyElement
```

Comment: The simple answer to your question about casting, would be, it works.  Isn't it already a number though?  Many thanks for your incredibly quick answer :)

Comment: As I said, it depends a bit on how you have declared or send the parameter to the template to begin with. If you make a new question with some more of your code we could probably explain it better for you. Happy it worked! :)

Comment: You are right about index typematch. But, I think you need to say something about precedence between `//` operator and predicates...

Comment: @Alejandro: You're of course right. However, I didn't really reflect over that issue since it wasn't part of the original question.

Answer (score 4):

**In XSLT 1.0/XPath 1.0 variables/parameters are not explicitly typed**.

Therefore, in XSLT 1.0 the solution is to use:

```
someExpression[position() = $i]
```

or

```
someExpression[number($i)]
```

**In XSLT 2.0** it is best to define the parameter as `xs:integer`:

```
<xsl:param name="i" as="xs:integer"/>
```

then using

```
someExpression[$i]
```

produces the wanted result.

**Do note, however**, that an expression like:

```
//ACommonElementInTheDocument[1]
```

doesn't select the first element in the document that is named `ACommonElementInTheDocument`.

This expression selects *every* `ACommonElementInTheDocument` element that is the first `ACommonElementInTheDocument` child of its parent -- therefore the above expression generally may return many elements and it is possible that none of them would be the first `ACommonElementInTheDocument` in the document.

**This is why the solution of @Per-T is most probably incorrect -- both in XSLT 1.0 and in XSLT 2.0**.

**Instead of**:

```
//ACommonElementInTheDocument[number($i)]/MyElement
```

**use**

```
(//ACommonElementInTheDocument)[number($i)]/MyElement
```

**Remember**: The `[]` operator binds stronger (has a higher precedence) than the `//` abbreviation.